# Validate/Authorize Current Password In Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, validation, authorization, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to add a password change feature for my logged in/authorized users. It's your plain ole generic set up:

```
Current Password
New Password
Confirm New Password
```

Obviously I can just use validate on the new password and password confirmation, but how do I authorize the current password submitted against their actual current password?

In the users model `password` is a hidden property so I can't just match them up.

I tried looking through `Illiminate\Auth` and `Guard` but I didn't see it anywhere.  Perhaps I missed it, or maybe I'm going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Let me know if my answer is what are you looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the answer in case anyone else is looking:

```
$validator = $this->validator($request->all());

$validator->after(function($validator) use ($request) {
    $check = auth()->validate([
        'email'    => $this->user->email,
        'password' => $request->current_password
    ]);

    if (!$check):
        $validator->errors()->add('current_password', 
            'Your current password is incorrect, please try again.');
    endif;
});

if ($validator->fails()):
    return redirect('account/password')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
endif;

$this->user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
$this->user->save();
```

Comment: Is it possible to add those checks in request directly?

Answer (score 1):

Get the current password and compare with the new password.

```
//use Auth, Hash, Input;

if (Hash::check(Input::get('new_password'), Auth::user()->password))
        echo "Matched";
else
        echo "Not matched";
```

Did you use the the laravel built in authentication package? If yes, the validation has been done for you. Check app/Http/Controller/Auth/AuthController.php, you can see this validation function. You can add more if you wish!:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}
```

If any error happens during the above validation, it will be sent to the $errors variable where your blade view can catch them. So, in your reset password view (view/auth/reset.blade.php), you can catch the validation errors as follow:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Weird it didn't work hen I tried that initially. But alas, this doesn't really help as much as I'd hope as I'll still need to write a custom validator to do the comparison. Hard to believe this isn't part of the validator already.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer. Did you use the laravel built in authentication package? If yes, you don't have to write custom validator. It's done for you, just that you need to display that error in the blade view. Please let me know if that is the answer your are looking for and if you need more clarification just ask. :)

Comment: Yeah it's clearly stated in the question that this is for logged in users. And yes they were created with the baked in auth system.

Comment: This isn't for reset password from the baked in `Auth\PasswordController` class. That's already set up and it's for folks who've forgotten their password. This is for logged in users who simply want to change their password as a normal security precaution.

Comment: Ok I missed that one. Then the custom validator need to be written but you can simply follow the same rule :)

Comment: Even trying to match the two in your original answer doesn't work. Strangely when I run `bcrypt()` on what I know is my password, that string doesn't match the password in `auth()->user()->password` weird.

Comment: Try this one instead: if (Hash::check(Input::get('new_password'), Auth::user()->password)).